# Transform array of objects by condition React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I am getting an array of objects from the server in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "country": "UK",
        "name": "Battery Ltd 1",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "name": "Technologies Inc. 1",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Jayne Mansfield",
        "type": "representative"
    },
    {
        "country": "China",
        "name": "Technologies Inc. 2",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Dan Borrington",
        "type": "representative"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Susan Reedy",
        "type": "representative"
    }
]
```

However, I need to iterate over this array of objects and convert it to this format: I want to combine the CONTACT type with the following REPRESENTATIVE object or objects. That is, at the output, I would like to get such an array with arrays:

```
[
    [
        {
            "country": "UK",
            "name": "Battery Ltd 1",
            "type": "contact"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "country": "USA",
            "name": "Technologies Inc. 1",
            "type": "contact"
        },
        {
            "country": "",
            "name": "Jayne Mansfield",
            "type": "representative"
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            "country": "China",
            "name": "Technologies Inc. 2",
            "type": "contact"
        },
        {
            "country": "",
            "name": "Dan Borrington",
            "type": "representative"
        },
        {
            "country": "",
            "name": "Susan Reedy",
            "type": "representative"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: What are the criteria for connecting? Always 3 objects?

Comment: There may be more objects. The main problem is that I can't figure out how to iterate over the array so that after each REPRESENTATIVE type, close the inner array if there is no further element or the next element of type CONTACT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go through the elements and create a group if element is a contact, and add to the group otherwise:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "country": "UK",
        "name": "Battery Ltd 1",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "name": "Technologies Inc. 1",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Jayne Mansfield",
        "type": "representative"
    },
    {
        "country": "China",
        "name": "Technologies Inc. 2",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Dan Borrington",
        "type": "representative"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Susan Reedy",
        "type": "representative"
    }
]

const result = data.reduce( (r, e) => (e.type === 'contact' ? r.push([e]) : r[r.length -1].push(e), r), [])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = []
let current = []
let hasRepresentative = false

for (const item of getItems()) {
  if (current.length === 0) {
    current.push(item)
    continue
  }
  if (hasRepresentative && item.type === 'contact') {
    array.push(current)
    current = [item]
    continue
  }
  current.push(item)
  hasRepresentative = true
}
array.push(current)

console.log(array)

function getItems() { return [
    {
        "country": "UK",
        "name": "Battery Ltd 1",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "USA",
        "name": "Technologies Inc. 1",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Jayne Mansfield",
        "type": "representative"
    },
    {
        "country": "China",
        "name": "Technologies Inc. 2",
        "type": "contact"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Dan Borrington",
        "type": "representative"
    },
    {
        "country": "",
        "name": "Susan Reedy",
        "type": "representative"
    }
]
}
```